# How to create a volatile market, by combining less volatile markets?

Tags: volatility, random-walk, random-variables

This might be against the law of gravity, but I'll give a try

Is there a way to combine two financial products $p_1$ and $p_2$, into a single product $p_c$ that is more volatile than its components?

Mathematically, if the daily returns of the original products are:

$$r_1\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$$
$$r_2\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$$

Can I build a financial product whose daily returns are:

$$r_c\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_c,\,\sigma_c^{2})$$
$$\sigma_c > \sigma$$

Careful:

- **I am not looking to increase volatility of absolute returns.** (e.g. returns in USD). That is easy,  just use leverage. But with leverage come proportionally higher transaction costs. So you don't have an extra edge in trading.
- **I am looking to increase volatility of relative returns** (e.g. percentage returns). I want  to obtain higher volatility, at stable transaction costs. That would be an extra hedge in trading.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about what you mean with absolute/percentage returns? Is absolute returns the returns in USD? Then increase the investment. Is relative returns the returns relative to the investment? Then use leverage. What am I missing?

Comment: Got it! I will delete the question  and post it all differently  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Throw in correlation as the additional variable.

Similarly, volofvol could be another candidate to play with.

A spread option could have a larger volatility than either of the two underliers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be your two assets and $C$ your financial product. For now we only assume products which are a linear combination of $X_1$ and $X_2$ with no shorting allowed, hence:
$$\begin{align}
& C=\alpha X_1 + (1-\alpha)X_2
\\
& 0\leq \alpha \leq 1
\end{align}$$
Letting $\rho$ be the correlation between returns $r_1$ and $r_2$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
\sigma_c^2&=\alpha^2\sigma^2+(1-\alpha)^2\sigma^2+2\alpha(1-\alpha)\sigma^2\rho
\\
&=(1-2\alpha+2\alpha^2)\sigma^2+2\alpha(1-\alpha)\sigma^2\rho
\end{align}$$
You are asking under which conditions:
$$\sigma_c^2>\sigma^2$$
Namely:
$$(1-2\alpha+2\alpha^2)+2\alpha(1-\alpha)\rho>1$$
Rearranging and letting $\theta=2(1-\rho)\geq0$:
$$\theta\alpha^2-\theta\alpha+1>1$$
Namely:
$$\theta\alpha(\alpha-1)>0$$
but there is no value of $\alpha$ for which this inequality is enforced given our initial constraint $0\leq \alpha\leq1$. On the other hand, if you allow short-selling, namely $\alpha$ can take values lower than $0$ or higher than $1$, so some sort of leverage (where leverage in one asset is financed by shorting the other one), you observe that you manage to increase the volatility of the product $\sigma_c$ with respect to the underlying volatility $\sigma$.

Comment:  woooooo I've got to try this! the math seems to make sense, but I'm not getting the intuition yet. Let' me get back on this tomorrow